# Getting error Jenkin pipeline docker: command not found

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Dockerfile:

```
pipeline {
    agent  any
    stages {
        stage ('Compile') {
            steps {
                withMaven(maven: 'maven_3_6_3') {
                    sh 'mvn clean compile'
                }
            }
        }
        stage ('unit test and Package') {
            steps {
                withMaven(maven: 'maven_3_6_3') {
                    sh 'mvn package'
                }
            }
        }
        stage ('Docker build') {
            steps {
                sh 'docker build -t dockerId/cakemanager .'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- docker build -t dockerId/cakemanager .
  /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/CDCI-Cake-Manager_master@tmp/durable-e630df16/script.sh:

line 1: docker: command not found

Comment: if you need docker, you need to add a slave agent that has docker client. You'll need docker-in-docker image for this. [This](https://www.katacoda.com/courses/jenkins/build-docker-images) can be a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

First install docker plugin from **Manage Jenkins >> Manage Plugins >>** Click on available and search for **Docker** and install it[image].

and then configure it on **Manage Jenkins >> Global tool configuration**.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually install docker on your Jenkins master or on agents if you're running builds on them.

Here's the doc to install docker on OS X https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/install/

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. I was able to fix it successfully by following the steps listed here -

1. First of all, find the Jenkins Installation Directory on your MacOS.
   Open your terminal and run the following command :

`brew --prefix jenkins`

This command will output the path to the Jenkins installation directory within the Homebrew “cellar.”

If you installed Jenkins via Brew, then the `brew --prefix jenkins` command will give the above mentioned installation directory path, i.e. `/opt/homebrew/opt/jenkins-lts`

2. Now, locate the file ‘homebrew.mxcl.jenkins-lts.plist’ file situated at the path -> `/opt/homebrew/opt/jenkins-lts` and update its content as below -

a. Update string value for the 'ProgramArguments' key as follows -

`/opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk@17/bin/java`

b. Update string value for the '-jar' key as follows -
`/opt/homebrew/opt/jenkins-lts/libexec/jenkins.war`

c. Add the 'EnvironmentVariables' key as follows -

```
<key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
<dict>
    <key>PATH</key>
    <string>/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin/:/Users/himanshubector/Library/Group\ Containers/group.com.docker/Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin</string>
</dict>
```

Note: Please update the above bold highlighted values and replace it with the path/value that corresponds to your system’s directory structure. I am using openjdk 17.

3. Once you have updated the content of this `homebrew.mxcl.jenkins-lts.plist` file, restart the jenkins using the below brew command :

`brew services restart jenkins-lts`

4. Now, you can try running the Jenkins Pipeline build. After following these above listed steps, your Jenkins Pipeline on macOS should be able to find and use Docker for building Docker images without encountering the “Docker command not found” error.